# No line found for nextline/int

Tags: java, string, int, java.util.scanner

I try to let the user input some values in string and int in while loop, however, when I start I get no Line found I tried my best on my own to solve it but nothing worked for me. I wonder how I let the user input the values for the int and string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    int saldo = 10000;
    String anw = "j";
    int cost;


    //create file
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\ae65255\\Desktop\\file.txt");
    try{


        f.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("23");
                        //frågan
    while(anw.equals("j")){

        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(f);
        System.out.println("Ange utgiftspost:"); //post
        String post = fileIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ange kostnad:"); //kost
        cost=fileIn.nextInt();
        fileIn.nextLine();
        saldo = +saldo -cost; 
        System.out.println("saldo:" +saldo);
        System.out.println("Vill du mata in fler uppgifter? (j/n) :");
        anw = fileIn.nextLine();
        String fileContent = "---"+post+"---"+cost+"---"+saldo; 
        PrintWriter writer ;
           writer = new PrintWriter(f);
           writer.println(fileContent);


        if (anw.equals("n")) {
            fileIn.close();
            writer.close();
        //System.out.println("---"+post+"---"+cost+"---"+saldo);                

        }
    } //frågan slut


    }
      catch(Exception e){
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}//frågan
        //System.out.println("---"+post+"---"+cost+"---"+saldo);                
    System.out.println("File path" +f.getPath());

    }


}
```

Comment: you're reading from an empty file ... why? You have to read from console for user input: `new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: I first created that empty file then I tried to let the user put some values that are going to be sent to file.txt.

Comment: Nevertheless, the scanner has to read from console for user input, so as I said `new Scanner(System.in);` - and for writing to file use `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));` and then call `append()` method for each line you want to write to file. Clearly, you copy pasted your code from somewhere without understanding what it does. Try to avoid this in the future - good luck

Comment: The only thing I copied was the part where it creates the txt file other than that I did everything on my own.

Comment: fair enough. I hope you understood my suggestions what to use for which task, I guess you already solved the problem now?

Comment: @ASKW I found out a way but didn't take your advice, unfortunately. I have tho looked up about buffered writer and append but on the docs online but quite didn't understand it. The only problem I have now in my program is that it over writer the txt file.

Comment: if you would use my solution, `new FileWriter(f, true);` - the second argument here is "append" mode for the file opened. For your simple case, a `BufferedWriter` wouldn't be possible, i.e. create a `FilterWriter` before the `while` loop with `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f, true);` and then call `writer.append(stringToWrite);writer.flush();` as well as after the loop finished  `writer.close()`
    writer.append(stringToWrite);`

Comment: You know the code about (f, true) that I found out too but didn't know where to put it in the code I got always an error, but thanks to you it knows works thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AKSW comment solved my two answers. Using `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` would let me take the user input from the console. The other was to stop it overwrite the text it which was his latest [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380519/no-line-found-for-nextline-int?noredirect=1#comment99408994_56380519) on this post.